# All editing icon buttons lost when entering edit mode for the user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-profile-page, user-interface

I got surprised when entering edit mode for our user profile.

No icon button for editing left. Where are they?

[image]

I need icon buttons to insert image, make header, make bulleted lists, etc.

It also happened in StackOverflow as follows:

[image]

Comment: You mean the normal edit buttons to format code blocks, insert images etc.? They are really gone it seems.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: What's about the red stuff? It is quite diverting.  Did you tried to censor the content? Simply deleting it for the screenshot would have been enough. The data is public anyway (Ok, not the source code itself)

Comment: @Stefan: I use Firefox 5 under Ubuntu 11.04, all up-to-date. The 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons are there but the icon bar on top is missing.

Comment: Maybe someone has requested to remove the buttons as a new feature.

Comment: I suggest migrating it to the main meta site. I could not see the button on stackoverflow too. Can comebody conform the problem for other SE sites than TeX.SE?

Comment: @Stefan: It also happened in SO. See my update please.

Comment: I believe that  this bug (or maybe feature) happens in all SE and SO sites. I have checked some of them, they have the same issue.

Comment: @Stefan, xport: This question got looked by Community here and also deleted (404 Error) at Meta.SX. I reopened and unlocked it, so I can add this comment. Any suggestions how to proceed with it?

Comment: @xport: Could you tell use if the issue is fixed now for you. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I just checked and the buttons are there again. It might have been a temporary issue with the recent UI updates. Could the OP please check again if the issues still exists.

Comment: I can confirm that the buttons re-appeared.